# Deploy angular to IIS error: Failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404? Anyone can help me?

Tags: angular, iis, deployment, resources

This is error msg in Chrome Console when I try to run my Angular web on server :
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX5UD.png)

Comment: The actual deployment steps are long, https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration so you have to read them through first and make sure you didn't miss any. If the errors persist, enable FRT to learn more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 1):

As your code is not provided, I can only guess. Assets folder is not accessible and this makes me think that your applications base value is not right. Can you check

```
<base href="/relative_directory_of_your_content_in_the_web_server">
```

in your index.html and the web server is configured right?